# designing a memory management scheme from a 48-bit architecture

Tags: memory-management, paging, page-tables

My goal is to create a clear translation scheme from a 48 bit logical address to a 48 bit physical address. I want to use Page Tables to complete this project. Does anyone know what Physical memory size and frame size would make sense for this memory management scheme?

I am thinking of a 1kb frame size but that makes my page table look a too large based off of what i'm seeing in online examples. Any resources to help would be great. I attached a screenshot of what I have so far.

The screenshot below shows the starting address and ending address of each frame (0-47). P1 and P2 are processes. P1 requires 3000 bits of memory and P2 requires 4000 bits of memory. the Frame for each index is what each index is assigned to. (p1 index 0 is assigned to frame 1, index 2 is assigned to frame 2, index 2 is assigned to frame 4)
Thank you!
[image: excel spreadsheet of page table.]

Comment: I think you should explain more clearly, in words, what your goals and constraints are.  The spreadsheet is impossible to understand without context.

Comment: @NateEldredge I added more to clarify my goal and explain what's going on. does that make sense?